# How to Disable Material Design Style in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml

I am using [Material Design in XAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) to style my WPF UI controls. I defined the default theme in the App.xaml file.

```xaml
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

However, I want some of my controls to have the default WPF look and feel, but it looks like the Material Design in XAML overrides the WPF default control style.

Example: The button below automatically takes its style from the Material design without specifying it.

```xaml
<Button Content="Hello" Width="100"/>
```

How can I disable the Material Design in some controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `Style` property to `x:Null` makes it fall back to the default `Style` that is implemented in the framework assembly:

```
<Button Content="Hello" Width="100" Style="{x:Null}" />
```

The other option would be to remove the `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />` from your `App.xaml` and explicitly set the `Style` property of all controls that do you want to have the Material Design look.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty style inside a ResourceDict like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="styleless" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and assign it to your button like this:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource styleless}" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work.  I was setting the button style to null like this: `<Button  Style="{x:Null}"/>` and then I thought there could be a better way to remove the material design default style.